# Are resolve/fix/handle/deal with interchangeable in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, difference

> You have some issues right now that you need to resolve/fix/handle/deal with, so I don't think we should start dating anytime soon.

Are these interchangeable and equally natural? Which one do you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

In this context (dating) I think they all mean basically the same thing. There *are* subtle differences:

- To resolve = to find and implement a solution to a problem
- Fix = to repair or mend something that is (either literally or figuratively) broken
- Handle = to take steps to manage something that you are responsible for
- Deal with = to do something about a situation or problem

Again, in the context of not wanting to date someone, all of these words will get your point across. Personally, I would probably say "deal with" in most interpersonal situations of this nature.